# no POST after js form.submit() in Selenium

Tags: javascript, python, html, testing, selenium

I'm using Selenium for testing a simple website which searches a database and displays the results. Each form for searching, uploading files and logging in work fine during the Selenium tests. The results page is loading correctly and elements are being selected correctly.

After selecting elements, a form is created and submitted. This all works manually and up until a few hours ago (during which the code hasn't changed, I've checked the diff) it worked with Selenium too.

Now everything is working as it should until the form.submit(). The javascript reaches this line and then there is no POST in the server logs.
In the client logs this appears:

[WEBDRIVER] [INFO] synthetic_mouse.js:9914 Called fireMouseEvent mousemove 1032.2000122070312, 100, [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLInputElement]]

[WEBDRIVER] [INFO] synthetic_mouse.js:9812 SyntheticMouse.click [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLInputElement]]

[WEBDRIVER] [INFO] synthetic_mouse.js:9824 About to do a bot.action.click on [object XrayWrapper [object HTMLInputElement]]

[WEBDRIVER] [INFO] command_processor.js:8089 Not loading document anymore.

Here is the js code, called after the delete although I don't think it is the problem (selectedBoxes contains the id of each checked box):

```
 function on_load() {
  var delBut = document.getElementById("delete");
  delBut.addEventListener("click", function(){
   if(selectedBoxes.length > 0)
     createForm("delete");
  } );
 }
 function createForm(which, forSale)
 {
 //create form
 var f = document.createElement("form");
 f.setAttribute('method',"post");
 f.setAttribute('action',"/results/");
 //get changed values
 for (var i = 0; i < selectedBoxes.length; ++i) {
  //create input object
  var input = document.createElement("input");
  //use text so values can be read on server side
  input.setAttribute("type", "text");
  input.setAttribute("name", which);
  input.setAttribute("value", '{"db_id":'+ selectedBoxes[i] + '}');

 }
 //send new form
 f.submit();
}


window.onload = on_load();
```

And selenium code:

```
 driver = webdriver.Firefox()
 driver.get("http://foo.bar.com")
 els = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//td/input[@name='select']")
 for el in els:
    el.click()
 driver.find_element_by_id("delete").click()
```